# Upload a file stream to AZURE BLOB STORAGE using REST APIs

Tags: azure, azure-blob-storage, rest, azure-rest-api

I am trying to upload a file stream to Azure Blob using the below code:

```
 const requestOptions = {
    url: url,
    method: 'PUT',
    headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'application/octet-stream',
      'Content-Length': contentLength,
      'x-ms-blob-type': 'BlockBlob',
      'x-ms-date': strTime,
      'x-ms-version': '2019-02-02'
    },
    body: readStream
 }
```

The data stream which I have is too large and I cannot store it in memory and stall the code flow to calculate the content length, so is there any way to make the REST request to upload blob without the content length?

I came across a solution [Link](https://azuresdkdocs.blob.core.windows.net/$web/dotnet/Azure.Storage.Blobs/12.0.0/api/index.html) Where they try to make upload call without the content length of the file or stream. Is such a thing possible to making use of REST or any other method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> so is there any way to make the REST request to upload blob without
> the content length?

Content length is required when uploading a blob so you cannot omit that from your request. From this [`link`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/put-blob#request-headers-all-blob-types):

[image]

If your input data is too large, one possible solution would be to read input data in chunks and upload them using [`Put Block`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/put-block) operation and then finally performing [`Put Block List`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/put-block-list) to commit the blob.